# How to manipulate the dataset fetched from Solr through R?

Tags: r, solr

I have used the following code to fetch the data from solr. But i want to save the following data in a dataframe and manipulate the local dataframe. Any help on the same would be appreciated .
My Code:

```
datasetInput <- reactive({url <- 'http:/**************/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json'
  solr_search(q=input$obs, fl='proj, fun, country, recfilename, attribute, value, ts_stop, ts_start', rows=20, base=url)})
```

How can i fetch each row from the dataset individually ?

Comment: are you using `solrium`? you can adjust the `rows` parameter to say how many records to get back